# Video Stretching in Ant Media Community Edition

Tags: ant-media-server-sdk

If I am streaming from android webrtc SDK (provided by antmedia) to community edition of Ant Media, the final video which is being saved, appears stretched (shot in portrait mode of mobile). [Check the screenshot of the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgQRw.jpg).
But if I am using the enterprise edition, the problem resolves itself.

Kindly help, how can I prevent the video stretching (while saving) in community edition?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. 

I think this problem happens because Ant Media Server Community Edition resizes the incoming video to 640x480. The origin video's resolution is likely 16:9 so that you see a stretching in the video.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem happens because Ant Media Server Community Edition resizes the incoming video to 640x480. The origin video's resolution is likely 16:9 so that you see a stretching in the video.

I think you can set the resolution to something 4:3 in Android SDK because community edition uses 640x480 for converting WebRTC stream. Try the followings before you initialize `webRTCClient = new WebRTCClient( this,this);`  in `onCreate` method

```
  this.getIntent().putExtra(EXTRA_VIDEO_WIDTH, 640);
  this.getIntent().putExtra(EXTRA_VIDEO_HEIGHT, 480);
```

### Update:

There is an aspect ratio problem in community edition while publishing from Mobile App. The issue is created for that. https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/issues/2492

Fortunately, commits are also pushed to resolve this problem. It'll be available as SNAPSHOT soon and will be available in next release.
SNAPSHOTs are here -> [https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;gav~io.antmedia~ant-media-server~~~~kw,versionexpand](https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;gav%7Eio.antmedia%7Eant-media-server%7E%7E%7E%7Ekw,versionexpand)

Comment: How can the same problem be solved in iOS? Kindly tell the steps to fix the issue in iOS webrtc SDK as well.

Comment: Good question.  There is a method in iOS SDK with name `setTargetResolution` 
You can specify width and height there and try again. 
https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/wiki/WebRTC-iOS-SDK-Reference

Comment: `setTargetResolution` is overriden in `startCapture()` method of `WebRTCClient.swift` in which it is matched with the nearest `AVCaptureDevice.Format`. Tried multiple combinations and it didn't work. Tried this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089336/ios-how-to-change-video-resolution-in-webrtc) also, but didn't work.

Comment: Just now checked the suggestion for Android. That didn't work either. Kindly check yourself.

Comment: Do you see output log of the below line in android? 
Logging.d(TAG, "startCapture: " + width + "x" + height + "@" + framerate);

If yes and it's not 640x480, it means your device camera may not support 640x480. You may try some other 4x3 ratios

Comment: In iOS side, it tries to find the closest resolution in startCapture method.

Comment: I don't think it's iOS or android problem or camera support problem. The question states clearly that the issue occurs only when we use community edition, not the enterprise edition.

Comment: Checked in android: startCapture: 640*480@30fps 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glvn5.jpg. No problem there.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Because it's in community edition. We give support as best effort. I'm checking for now.

Comment: Yeah I've encountered some problems in Android SDK and community edition. Because generally it's designed for Enterprise edition. Anyway I'll try to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in video player activity

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/player_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:resize_mode="fill"
            app:use_controller="false" />
```